# applying for permissions other than basic for instagram non-Business accounts

Tags: android, instagram

I am working on an application for Samsung Gear watch to access Instagram and display user's photos and photos from people they follow. About 2 weeks ago  I was able to apply for permissions other than basic, such as follower-list and public_content. However today I don't see any possibility to apply for additional permissions. Instead, I read "We no longer offer additional permissions to new applications using the legacy API."

I understand that there is a policy change and once I was directed to use new Instagram API. But I am not building apps for Instagram Business Accounts. I am interested in developing an app for Instagram users to see their follower photos on platforms that do not yet have an Instagram client.

So how can I apply for these permissions on non-Business accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you need to create a new Instagram client and go through the whole permissions process from the beginning.

Comment: ok but from which platform ? the original api request form does not allow adding additional permissions.

Comment: From Instagram, not Facebook. You can no longer add permissions to an existing client, you must unfortunately create a whole new Instagram API client, and then apply for all the permissions you need from scratch. You basically have to start over in order to add new permissions. Of course do not delete your old client until the new one is working.

Comment: ok but from which address shall I apply for permissions ? Old API request address does not have additional permissions submitable now. So which address to apply ?